# How to build uberJar with Quarkus-Gradle-Plugin

Tags: java, gradle-plugin, quarkus

I'm trying to build an uberJar with all the dependencies (runnable) using the Quarkus Gradle plugin. 
With maven you can build it by adding a config to the plugin.

That's what it looks like in maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <uberJar>true</uberJar>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there any possibility to set this property in the gradle plugin?
id 'io.quarkus.gradle.plugin' version '0.12.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of that option is "uber-jar".
To set this property you have to start the build like that from command line:

```
>gradle quarkusBuild --uber-jar
```

I had some bugs during the build, like that one

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/sven/Idea/getting-started/build/getting-started.jar
```

but in the end the build was successful

Comment: There have been a lot changes to the Gradle support after 0.12.0 so I would suggest either building from master or waiting for 0.13.0 (in a few days) to see if you still have the same issues

Answer (score 1):

The `quarkusBuild` task contains a property named `uberJar` that you can be used to control the uberJar behavior (see [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/0.12.0/devtools/gradle/src/main/java/io/quarkus/gradle/tasks/QuarkusBuild.java#L52)).

Comment: Can I use this property on the commandline? Like gradle quarkusbuild -uberJar ?

Comment: You should be able to activate it by using `--uberJar=true`

Comment: gradle quarkusBuild --uberJar=true

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :quarkusBuild from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--uberJar'.

Comment: I'm not a gradle expert so I will need to look further to see what the proper syntax is

Comment: `-PuberJar=true` can be used from the command line

Answer (score 1):

You can directly configure the task in your `build.gradle` using something like:

```
task buildUberJar(type: io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusBuild, dependsOn: build) {
    uberJar = true
}
```

However, I see a lot of issues with overlapping resources between the jars with this approach. Here is a subset of my output:

```
> Task :service-asset-management:buildUberJar
building quarkus runner

Duplicate entry META-INF/quarkus-extension.json entry from io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson::jar:0.26.1(runtime) will be ignored. Existing file was provided by io.quarkus:quarkus-kubernetes-client::jar:0.26.1(runtime)
Duplicate entry NOTICE entry from org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients::jar:2.2.1(runtime) will be ignored. Existing file was provided by org.ehcache:ehcache::jar:3.6.1(runtime)
Duplicate entry META-INF/quarkus-extension.json entry from io.quarkus:quarkus-arc::jar:0.26.1(runtime) will be ignored. Existing file was provided by io.quarkus:quarkus-kubernetes-client::jar:0.26.1(runtime)
Duplicate entry META-INF/quarkus-extension.json entry from io.quarkus:quarkus-core::jar:0.26.1(runtime) will be ignored. Existing file was provided by io.quarkus:quarkus-kubernetes-client::jar:0.26.1(runtime)
Dependencies with duplicate files detected. The dependencies [org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients::jar:2.2.1(runtime), org.ehcache:ehcache::jar:3.6.1(runtime)] contain duplicate files, e.g. NOTICE
Dependencies with duplicate files detected. The dependencies [io.quarkus:quarkus-core::jar:0.26.1(runtime), io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson::jar:0.26.1(runtime), io.quarkus:quarkus-kubernetes-client::jar:0.26.1(runtime), io.quarkus:quarkus-arc::jar:0.26.1(runtime)] contain duplicate files, e.g. META-INF/quarkus-extension.json
Dependencies with duplicate files detected. The dependencies [commons-logging:commons-logging::jar:1.2(runtime), org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j::jar:1.7.25(runtime)] contain duplicate files, e.g. org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog$1.class
```